# iterate through a list of lists of strucs in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, higher-order-functions

given a list of the following form:

```
(define lst (list
    (list
    (make-route-section 32 'ordinary-road 23 0.45)
    (make-route-section 54 'ordinary-road 92 0.83)
    (make-route-section 14 'street 8 0.82)
    (make-route-section 44 'ferry 34 0.64)
    (make-route-section 96 'ferry 249 0.41)
    )(
    list
    (make-route-section 92 'ordinary-road 12 0.44)
    (make-route-section 98 'highway 45.243 0.3)
    (make-route-section 44 'ordinary-road 34.4 0.64)
    (make-route-section 39 'street 6 0.8)
    )(
    list
    (make-route-section 62 'highway 82 0.35)
    (make-route-section 58 'street 4 0.46)
    (make-route-section 50 'highway 81 0.24)
    (make-route-section 75 'highway 67.3 0.39)
    )
    )
```

A route section is the following:

```
    (define-struct route-section (id kind length eco-index))
    (define-struct traffic-jam (section-id delay))
```

How would I, for example filter out certain structs with given ids (first field of the struct) with a list like (list 32 62) and it would return me the second element of the outer list. What confused me especially is, when I entered (second lst) it returned the second element of the first list of the whole list.

How would I add up the lengths of the route sections? I feel so dumb, even using higher order functions I could't iterate through the nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to sum the length of the route.

A route is a list of *segments*, each segment is a list of sections, which are structures.

To sum a list of numbers a good approach is `(foldl + 0 <list>)`.  But we don't have a list of numbers, we have a list of segments.  So we want to get a number from each segment.  We could use `foldl` again.  But each element of the segment isn't a number: it's a section.  So a good way of taking a list of somethings and getting a list of something-elses is to use `(map <function-to-turn-something-into-something-else> <list-of-somethings>)`.

`route-section-length` will take a section object and return its length, so that's the function we want to map.  So we could start, on a segment, to turn it into a list of lengths of its sections:

```
(map route-section-length <segment>)
```

And now we have a list of numbers for each segment, and we can use `foldl`:

```
(foldl + 0 (map route-section-length <segment>))
```

And this will turn a segment into a number.  Well, we have a list of segments, so we want to turn them into a list of numbers, which we can do by mapping a function whose body is the expression above over the list:

```
(map (λ (segment)
         (foldl + 0 (map route-section-length segment)))
       route)
```

OK, that gives us a list of numbers, which we now need to add up, again using `foldl`:

```
(foldl + 0
         (map (λ (segment)
                (foldl + 0 (map route-section-lenght segment)))
              route))
```

And that, wrapped in a definition, is what we want.

---

Also: *indent your code properly*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the educational explanation! Really helped me out here.